# RxJs not switchMap if an error occured in the top level subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

If my first Observable throws an error, then i would not subscribe to my switchMap observable.

Is this possible?

```
this._profileService.updateProfile(profile).pipe(
  tap(profile => {
    this.profile = profile;
    this.saving = false;
    this.updateForm(this.profile);
  }),
  catchError(error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.saving = false;
    this.updateForm();
    return this._pjNotificationService.show(PjNotificationType.ERROR, 'Fehler beim Speichern',
      `Beim Speichern ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. ${error}`, 15000)
  }),
  switchMap(() => this._pjNotificationService.show(PjNotificationType.SAVED, 'Änderungen gespeichert', '', 15000))
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the order of your operators, the observable returned by `catchError` will continue to the `switchMap`.

You can change the order of your operators so that the `switchMap` comes before the `catchError`:

```js
this._profileService.updateProfile(profile).pipe(
  tap(profile => {
    this.profile = profile;
    this.saving = false;
    this.updateForm(this.profile);
  }),
  switchMap(() => this._pjNotificationService.show(PjNotificationType.SAVED, 'Änderungen gespeichert', '', 15000)),
  catchError(error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.saving = false;
    this.updateForm();
    return this._pjNotificationService.show(PjNotificationType.ERROR, 'Fehler beim Speichern',
      `Beim Speichern ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. ${error}`, 15000)
  })
).subscribe();
```

This way, the `switchMap` will get skipped if `this._profileService.updateProfile(profile)` throws an error, as it will jump to the `catchError`.

Comment: Oh tanks, its working. I thought if i switchMap before the catchError i only catch the errors of the second Observable.

Comment: You catch all the errors from every operator before the `catchError` :)